# Uniform continuity of a bounded function on an unbounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Are all bounded continuous functions on an unbounded interval uniformly continuous ?

Comment: Think about $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: sin(x^2) is a periodic function. so it is uniform continuous. then what is the specialty of this function?

Comment: No, $\sin(x^2)$ is not periodic. What's special about it is that it's a bounded continuous function which is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @DEEP No, $\sin(x^2)$ is not periodic. Consider the unbounded derivative to see that it isn't periodic and also not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Having an unbounded derivative shows a function is not periodic. It does not imply that the function is not uniformly continuous! There are plenty of uniformly continuous functions out there with unbounded derivative.

Comment: sorry... My mistake .

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you give me an example of an uniformly continuous function with an unbounded derivative? Edit: Ah okay, I realized my fallacy.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain The example you posted is in fact such an example. There are simpler examples possible, where the derivative is continuous but unbounded as you go to infinity. (If $f'(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ _that_ would imply $f$ was not uniformly continuous...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What do you think about this statement: Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be function with continuous derivative. If there exists a $\delta>0$ such that the measure of $A_n:=\{x\in\mathbb R \mid |f'(x)|>n\}$ is at least $\delta$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain $\sin(x^2)$ is a counterexample. Say $I_n=[x_n,y_n]$, where $x_n$ and $y_n$ are as in my "answer". Show that $\sum|I_n|=\infty$ and that $f'\ge cn$ on roughly the left half of $I_n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How can a not uniformly continuous function be a counter-example to my statement?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Sorry, read something backwards. Say $f=0$ except for a sequence of triangular bumps. The $n$-th bump has base $[n-1/n,n+1/n]$ and height $1/\sqrt n$. Then $f$ is continuous and tends to $0$ at infinity, so $f$ is uniformly continuous. But $|f'| = \sqrt n$ on the $n$-th bump. And the sum of the measure of those intervals is infinite.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The sum may be infinite but you won't find my $\delta$. So this is still no counter-example. Furthermore, you first have to smoothen your function. Your function is not differentiable.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain So smooth out the bumps. For every $n$ the set where $|f'|>n$ has _infinite_ measure. So we just need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $\delta <\infty$. (After smoothing out we still have an interval $I_j$ of length $c/j$ where $|f'|>c\sqrt j$. So $|f'|>cn$ on the union of $I_j$ for $ j>n^2$. That union has infinite measure.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah, sorry. You're right again ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is given by $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$.

Let $x_n=\sqrt{2\pi n}$ and $y_n=\sqrt{2\pi n+\pi/4}$. Then $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1.$$
But $|x_n-y_n|\to0$. So $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

(One way to see that $|x_n-y_n|\to0$ is to apply the Mean Value Theorem to the function $\phi(t)=\sqrt t$.)

Comment: Now i understand .. it is a strong logic.. thank u sir..

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is not necessarily. The counter example provided by @DavidC.Ullrich demonstrates this.

A common reason a function is not uniformly continuous is that its derivative is actually unbounded (but a uniformly continuous function can actually have an unbounded derivative). For instance, if $g(x)=\sin(x^2)$ then $g'(x) = 2x \cos(x^2)$ which can take arbitrarily large positive and negative values.

If a differentiable function has a derivative that is bounded over the whole real line, then it would be uniformly continuous. This follows from the mean value theorem.

For instance suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and that $|f'(x)| < M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. When we consider $x < y$ and $$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)||x-y|$$ where $\xi \in (x,y)$, then we can see that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x-y|.$$

Now suppose we let $\epsilon > 0$. If we fix $x_0$, and consider all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_0 - y| < \epsilon/M$ we see that $$|f(x_0) - f(y)| < \epsilon.$$ Finally, since $\epsilon/M$ is independent of $x_0$, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: "If derivative exists and is bounded through the interval then the function is uniformly continuous " ... it is a sufficient condition but not necessary..

Comment: No it is not necessary. I didn't suggest that. In fact, principle-ideal-domain's function is uniformly continuous with an unbounded derivative.

Comment: I added a parenthetical remark to this effect. @DEEP